# Change the data hard drive - Ubuntu Server

Tags: partitioning, mount, hard-drive

Relatively new to Ubuntu, I consider myself quite a newbies. I have managed to install an Ubuntu Server 16.04 to an old PC. The OS is on the internal drive and the data is on an external 3Tb USB drive. I use it mainly for Owncloud, Samba, Plex and Roon. I need now to upgrade my external HDD to a 8Tb drive.

```
edwin@ubuntu:~$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           386M   21M  365M   6% /run
/dev/sda2       454G  7.0G  424G   2% /
tmpfs           1.9G   20K  1.9G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sdb1       2.7T  1.8T  774G  71% /media/data
/dev/sda1       511M  3.4M  508M   1% /boot/efi
tmpfs           386M     0  386M   0% /run/user/1000
```

Is it correct if I rsync the entire /media/data folder to the new formated drive and then change the UUID of the new drive in the fstab and that's it?

Do I have to stop the owncloud service before doing that? Is it not better to use the DD command instead?

Any help/ideas is greatly appraciated!

Answer (score 1):

> change the UUID of the new drive in the fstab

That will need a reboot to take effect, or you'll have to manually unmount and remount.

> Do I have to stop the owncloud service before doing that?

If the ownclowd service might change anything in `/media/data` while you're copying to the new disk, then you should stop the service before the copying. The same goes for any other service which might use that directory.

Also, if you chose to manually unmount and remount, then you should stop the services that might read from the disk beforehand.

> Is it not better to use the DD command instead?

`rsync` is sufficient to get the data across. `dd` will just waste time - it will copy 2.7TB of data, when you only need to copy 1.8TB.

Comment: Great! sudo rsync -azvv /home/path/folder1/ /home/path/folder2 is enough for this, right?

Comment: @Edwin no point in using `-z`, since the transfer isn't over the network.

Comment: One alternative is to use file system aware dump utilities which will only copy used blocks. This will preserve the UUID.